# Excel based form with associated worfklows

Tags: sharepoint-online

I've been assigned the task of creating a quote system in SharePoint (as a development task as a company we are completely new to SharePoint Online). Essentially the spreadsheet is a form that requests handful of information.

I need to achieve something like the below (if it is even possible):

```
User opens Excel Spreadsheet Template and fills in document
Document is saved to a Doc Library (best solution?) as a  copy, but the original cannot be modified. 
(A workflow?) then emails the document to an estimator who will produce a quote.
```

Naturally I'm not looking for a step by step guide but just a high level overview if possible. Finally, would this be achieveable on a public facing website as well?

Comment: Does anything need to happen to the spreadsheet once it's saved to the library? Are you trying to extract data from it or just alert someone that a new spreadsheet was uploaded? How will you know WHO uploads the file? Something to consider.

Comment: Just alert someone that the new filled in spreadsheet has been added to the library. It will only be known 365 users working from the doc but so the modified flag on the document would say?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information you've provided, I think the following would be your best course of action.

Allow the users to simply download the spreadsheet template from your site. They can work on it offline. Once they've completed it, allow them to upload their file to your document library.

As for the alerts, your easiest option would be to allow your coworkers to manage their own alerts.

Go to the library -> Library Tab -> Alert Me button -> Set alert on this library

If you need something more customized, you can create a workflow in SharePoint Designer.